# ColdFusion - What's an efficient way to search an array of structs?

Tags: algorithm, arrays, search, coldfusion, struct

I have a semi-large (hundreds of records) 1-dimensional array in ColdFusion. Each item in the array is a struct with several properties. I want to search the array for a struct that has a specific "name" property. I know that for an array of string values I could use Java methods like so:

```
<cfset arrayIndex = myArray.indexOf("WhatImLookingFor") + 1>
```

...but that won't work for an array of structs. I also know I could brute-force it like this:

```
<cfset arrayIndex = 0>
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(myArray)#" index="counter">
    <cfif myArray[counter].name IS "WhatImLookingFor">
        <cfset arrayIndex = counter>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

...but I feel like there must be a more efficient way. Does anyone have a better solution than this? You can assume that the "name" property is present in every struct and there are no gaps or other objects in the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have a hash table you're creating as you build the array, I don't see how you're going to create a search function that is faster than the O(n) solution you've posted.  Anyway, while you are building your arrays, you could do something like this:

```
<cfloop query="qryValues">
    <cfset nameValues[name] = currentrow />
    <cfset myArray[currentrow].name = name />
</cfloop>

<cfset arrayIndex = nameValues["WhatImLookingFor"] />
```

This assumes that the value always exists.  You may need to check StructKeyExists(nameValues, "WhatImLookingFor") before making the call.

Answer (score 9):

In CF 10 or Railo 4, you can use:

```
arrayIndex = ArrayFind(arrayOfStructs, function(struct){ 
   return struct.name == "WhatImLookingFor"; 
});
```

It is not documented, but it works! ArrayFindAll() is also an option if you want all of the indices.

Comment: This class of new functions is great.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it works when searching for multiple criteria.  I don't know if there is any new ways of doing this, but glad to have found this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at it too deeply, I would consider converting the structure to a query (below) and then doing do a query of a query.. assuming your dataset isn't too huge!

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/264-Ask-Ben-Converting-A-Struct-To-A-Query-And-More-Java-.htm

Do share what you ended up doing!

Edit: The StructFindValue suggested looks to be excellent as well, I didn't think to look up any relevant functions.

Answer (score 0):

You either want to use StructFindValue or StructFindKey

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000640.htm#137597

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000639.htm#137550

Answer (score 0):

[CFGroovy](http://barneyb.com/cfgroovy/) FTW! :)

```
<cfset count = 0>
<g:script>
count = myArray.find({ 
  it["NAME"] == "WhatImLookingFor" }
})
</g:script>
```

or.. if you like a more java style (w/o closure)

```
<cfset count = 0>
<g:script>
for (i in myArray) {
  if( i["NAME"] == "WhatImLookingFor" )
    count++
}
</g:script>
```

Comment: Is this solution any better than the original algorithm posted in the question? I'm not well read on Groovy (or CFGroovy) yet, but it *looks* like you've just re-written the same algorithm in another language. For what it's worth, that is slightly more readable, and arguably more elegant... but it's chances of being faster are (probably) slim-to-none, considering it has to shell out to Groovy to run, and return to CF. I suppose if it's tremendously faster in Groovy then it's possible the overhead is worth it, but I doubt it.